# jquery check for form field length

Tags: jquery, validation

I have the following form and I want to ensure the user enters at least two characters before the form can be submitted. So I disable the submit button:

```
<form action="/search" method="post" id="search_form" name="searchform">
<input id="search_box" type="text" class="inp" placeholder="Search" />
<input type="submit" id="search_button" disabled class="btn" value="Search">
</form>
```

Am trying the following Jquery to capture the keypresses but not happening:

```
$("#search_box").keypress(function() {
if($(this).length > 1) {
     $('#search_button').removeAttr('disabled');
}
});
```

I've set up a fiddle to show: http://jsfiddle.net/HZvSF/3/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get the `val()` of your textbox:

```
$("#search_box").keypress(function() {
if($(this).val().length > 1) {
     $('#search_button').removeAttr('disabled');
}
});
```

**edit**

I just saw the library was MooTools in fiddle, here it is working:
http://jsfiddle.net/HZvSF/17/

Comment: change the javascript library to Jquery on leftside, it works.

Comment: However, in chrome you need 3 characters for some reason not two - also, there is a bug with every browser... if you key in say 4 characters, then delete them all, the submit button does not revert to being disabled... is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

I think it is a problem of binding. inside the anonymous function "this" does not refer to je JQuery object but to window I think.

```
$("#search_box").keypress(function(event) {
if($(event.target).val().length > 1) {
     $('#search_button').removeAttr('disabled');
}
});
```

Comment: $("this") does refer to the textbox object